# Setting Root View Controller Resets Level

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, game-center

I have the following code to open Game Center in my app (this is in an `SKView` class):

```
    GKGameCenterViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    leaderboardController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    leaderboardController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThisView"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:vc];
    [vc presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

It opens Game Center but does 3 things wrong:

1. The `setRootViewController` resets the my view controller (as if it were opened again).
2. When I close it, it makes everything super laggy (the FPS goes from 30 straight to 15).
3. I think in iOS 8 the Game Center background is even more transparent than before so my screen looks really dark and you can even see some of the labels on there. Here is a picture:

[image]

Any ideas on how I could fix any of those?

Also, I can only close Game Center once. If I open it again, it won't let me close it (I don't know if it's the lag or it just doesn't work).

Comment: For #1, of course it does, because you created a new instance of vc by calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: Well how do I fix it?